# Is it possible to make Oracle PL/SQL trigger as function and package?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two identical tables and to copy data from master table (Table 1) to backup table (Table 2), I have below trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER copy_Table1_to_Table2 AFTER INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO TABLE2 
   (col1, col2, ..., coln) 
VALUES 
   (:NEW.col1, :NEW.col2, ..., :NEW.coln);
END;
```

**Question 1:**
This works to copy data from one table to other. If I have to copy data from 20 different tables to 20 backup table (Identical), is it possible to have package or functions that takes arguments as table name and column names and reuse the same trigger instead of writing 20 different triggers?

If yes, would like to know how the code will look. Appreciate any help on this.

**Question 2:**
To make backup table (Table 2) as clone of master table (Table 1), do I have to truncate backup table first? So that no duplicate values are inserted (assuming master table has no duplicates).

Technically am loading bulk data into master table and insert trigger is inserting duplicates into backup table. Not sure how to avoid this scenario.

Am sorry if am asking too many questions, its just am not able to figure out best way to achieve the goal.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Richa

Comment: You'd still need a trigger on each table. It would probably be easier to generate those triggers programatically from the data dictionary. Or have the load process populate the master and backup tables at the same time, which would be even simpler and less opaque than relying on triggers.

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks for the response. I appreciate. Can you please guide me on how to generate triggers grammatically from data dictionary? Also how to do "have the load process populate the master and backup tables at the same time"

Comment: What is that "backup" used for? Both tables reside in the same schema, so I presume on the same hard disk. If it *dies*, backup tables will be lost too. So - what's the purpose of doing that? Why wouldn't you backup your tables (or, should I say, the whole database) properly? There are tools that enable you do that; export being rather popular (although not really a backup), RMAN, Data Guard, disk mirroring (RAID), ...

Comment: @Littlefoot. Thanks for the suggestion and for the question. I should have mentioned it in my OP. My bad. It makes perfect sense to have backup table on different database with different schema. At this stage I did not want to complicate the question on Stackoverflow so tried to keep it minimal and simple to meet end result. In practical, am having two schema on apex.oracle.com. Am using data load wizard to load bulk data into one schema1.table1 and to avoid re-upload of same data into schema2.table1, am trying to figure out if its possible to copy data from schema1.table1 to schema2.table1

Comment: continued.. So that I have data on schema2.table1 that is real time and equal to schema1.table1. This will help me to test queries and make changes to the application. in schema2 and then deploy it to schema1. Hope this helps. Please let me know if any questions or further explanation.